# Showing selected folder from the content node in tree-list is not working

Tags: sitecore-query, tree-list

Showing selected folder from the content node in tree-list is not working.
We have used the below query but looks like only parent node is visible not the child nodes.

```
DataSource=/sitecore/content/ABCed/ABC/Editorial/Content&AllowMultipleSelection=true&IncludeItemsForDisplay=article,ads,audio
```

Note: here article, ads and audio are folder names

Example tree structure.

```
category1 --> Article --> item1 and items2
Category1 --> Ads --> item1 and item2
category1 --> Video --> item1 and item2
category1 --> Audio --> item1 and item2
(Many more items)
```

Example - We wanted to showcase in the tree only article, ads and audio

We have tried through exclude query and other option but that would not work. Can you please suggest the right query here.

I need include query – as exclude query will not work and have to modify if new items will be created under data source location folder.
As an additional option, we tried IncludeTemplatesForDisplay filter, a comma separated list of templates names (no IDs) - items based on these templates will be shown to the author.

```
includetemplatesfordisplay=Item Name
```

This is also not working

Comment: can you please remove AllowMultipleSelection=true from your query and see if this helps?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading that tree right, then your problem here is that by excluding the `Catetgory` item in the display, Sitecore can then not show any children of a `Category`

So take this list:

```
category1 
    --> Article 
        --> item1 
        --> 
    --> Ads 
        --> item1 
        --> item2
    --> Video 
        --> item1 
        --> item2
    --> Audio 
        --> item1 
        --> item2
```

Structuring it like that shows that, if `category1` at the top of the tree is not included for display, none of the child items would show.

To limit what can be selected, you need to use a combination of `IncludeItemsForDisplay` and `IncludeItemsForSelection` or if you wanted to make if a bit more flexible, you could use `IncludeTemplatesForSelection`

```
DataSource=/sitecore/content/abc/abc/Editorial/Content&AllowMultipleSelection=true&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=category,article,ads,audio&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Add Templates Names here
```

You will have to base those settings on your actual tree and template scenarios, but just make sure that any parent items are not excluded for display by those settings, as you then will not see any child items.

See this post for more info on each of the options for a `treelist` https://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality

Comment: Very helpful inputs, thanks for sharing here